# ServiceWorker caching not stable

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Okay so I am just getting started with Service Workers.

I have the following code in my `sw.js`:

```
const cacheName = "v2"

// Call Install Event
self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
    console.log('Service Worker: Installed')

})

// Call Activate Event
self.addEventListener('activate', function (e) {
    console.log('Service Worker: Activated')

    // Remove unwanted caches
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(cache => {
                    if(cache != cacheName) {
                        console.log('Service Worker: Clearing Old Cache')
                        return caches.delete(cache)
                    }   
                })
            )
        })
    )
})


self.addEventListener('fetch', function (e) {
    console.log("Service Worker: Fetch")

    // var url = new URL(e.request.url)
    // console.log("Fetch page: " + url)

    e.respondWith(
        //fetch(e.request).catch(() => caches.match(e.request))
        fetch(e.request)
        .then(res => {
            // Make copy/clone of response
            const responseClone = res.clone()

            // Open Cache
            caches
            .open(cacheName)
            .then(cache => {
                // Add response to cache
                cache.put(e.request, responseClone)
            })
            return response
        }).catch(err => caches.match(e.request).then(res => res))
    )

})
```

Which I pretty much copied from a youtube video.  Now, my test site uses a number of CDNs, style sheets, and javascript files.  Some internal, some external.  Here is the list of errors I get in my console:

```
5sw.js:30 Service Worker: Fetch
5The FetchEvent for "<URL>" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().
The FetchEvent for "https://labs.domain.net/styles.css" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ sw.js:35
The FetchEvent for "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ sw.js:35
The FetchEvent for "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ sw.js:35
The FetchEvent for "https://labs.domain.net/javascript.js" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ sw.js:35
The FetchEvent for "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ sw.js:35
index.php:7 GET https://labs.domain.net/styles.css net::ERR_FAILED
index.php:9 GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_FAILED
index.php:11 GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_FAILED
index.php:45 GET https://labs.domain.net/javascript.js net::ERR_FAILED
index.php:10 GET https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

I don't get it.  When I click on the link that it is stating is failed, it loads correctly in the browser and I can see the contents of it.  The ones that are labled 'labs.domain.net' are on my server, and hosted right along side the sw.js file.  They also load correctly.  But for some reason the Service Worker is throwing all these errors.

If I click through the pages (I've got three, index.php, about.php and jimmeny.php) Before each page loads I get a 'this website cannot be reached' message then the page loads a few seconds after that.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong with this? My site is pretty damn simple, I don't understand why the resources wont save correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only send you a comment but the moderators kicked out a friend out as he did not log in for some time here, that just took a bit of my reputation to stop me commenting. Enough complaining...

Just wanted to let you know that you should consider what resources you are caching with the service worker. You would need to implement a cache controlling policy that suits best the application you are building.

In addition, each time your service worker installs a new version this does not necessarily mean that you start with a new cache, the cache can be managed independently from the service worker variants. I would recommend that you should start using both a versioned cache and service worker. This way you would be able to control better the situation. The cache is definitely stable.

To check what resources you have currently cached for Chrome, go to:
Developer Tools (Ctrl + Shift + I) -> Application (tab) -> Cache -> Cache Storage (expand this from the side menu) you should see "the name of your cache(s)", once you select "the cache name of interest" - "v2" you should see exactly what resources you have cached at the very precise moment you are looking at it.

Also, try to only cache resources that you have control over. Ie not from third parties as there might be some issues which need to be investigated. Remember that if your service worker is not controlling the third party resources you cannot expect it to be able to handle them. The service worker has as a scope below its current location on the domain name it was placed.

If you want to add permanently resources that are within the scope of control of your service worker until a new version of the service worker is released you could use something like this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    if (event.request.method === 'GET') { //only bother for static resources ;)
        switch (0) {
            case event.request.url.indexOf('https://www.google-analytics.com'):
            case event.request.url.indexOf('https://www.googletagmanager.com'):
                // skip adding to cache
                // console.warn('skip adding to cache ' + event.request.method + ' ' + event.request.mode + ' ' + event.request.url);
            break;
            case event.request.url.indexOf(SERVER_URL):
                // Cache falling back to network
                // console.info('[PWA] The service worker is serving an asset. ' + event.request.method + ' ' + event.request.mode + ' ' + event.request.url);
                event.respondWith(
                    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
                        return cache.match(event.request).then((response) => {
                            return response || fetch(event.request).then((response) => {
                                if (response.status === 200) {
                                    cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                                    return response;
                                } else if (response.type === 'opaqueredirect' || response.status === 404) {
                                    return response;
                                } else {
                                    return cache.match('offline.html');
                                }
                            }).catch(() => {
                                return cache.match('offline.html');
                            });
                        });
                    })
                );
            break;
            default:
            // console.warn('new case for cache ' + event.request.method + ' ' + event.request.mode + ' ' + event.request.url);
        }
    }
});
```

In this example, you would have cached "offline.html" upon SW installation so that you can display it when the user tries to access resources while offline and the resource was not previously cached. The method can be described as "serve cache or take resource from the network then serve from cache afterward". You would also need to implement logic to trim/replace/update the cache of static resources via the release of new service worker variants and execute this logic as and when needed.

Cheers!

Comment: Please note that the test (event.request.method === 'GET') does not guarantee that the resource is static due to back end being able to provide dynamic content. It all depends on what your situation is and you should plan accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this.  But I still cant understand why it fails on some of the resources and not all of them.  Do you have any explanation for that? They are valid URLs that point to files on my server or external, and for reasons I can't figure out they fail.  I get that the code you provided prevent that, and I will use it but I dont like things I can't explain!

Comment: Different resources can fail for different reasons, you just need to dig deeper, for example when the browser gets an redirect the browser would know how to handle it but your SW will need to be instructed what to do!

Comment: Another more complex reason would be when you send a Request to one file which would inform you to get your response from another file via instructions in the headers etc.. but again you would need to follow it up.

Comment: Yet another important fact is that the service workers operate from an entirely different environment and may need access to data they do not have ;-)